# Error CS0311 Generic Error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Error CS0311 The type 'HashTables.KeyValue<K, V>' cannot be used as type parameter 'Y' in the generic type or method 'BinarySearchTree'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'HashTables.KeyValue<K, V>' to 'System.IComparable<HashTables.KeyValue<K, V>>'.

Custom KeyValue Class

```
    public class KeyValue<K,V> where K : IComparable<K> where V : IComparable<V>
        
    {
       
        K key;
        V value;

      
        public KeyValue(K key, V value)
        {
            key = key;
            value = value;
        }

        public K Key
        {
            get
            {
                return key;
            }
        }

        public V Value
        {
            get
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for this error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0311

Comment: What is `KeyValue`? Given that it apparently does not implement `IComparable<KeyValue<K, V>>`, why do you think you should be able to use it as the type parameter for `BST<T>`?

Comment: When asking questions about errors on Stack Overflow, it is required that you provide the full error message content as text. Please read [ask] for more information about what is expected.

Comment: Error is saying that `KeyValue<V,T>` is not implementing `IComparable`. You are only putting restrictions on generic types of `KeyValue` not on the whole type. That triggers an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your KeyValue a little. The problem is that your KeyValue is actually the element that you want to compare in your tree (most probably by value). Null checking omitted for clarity.

```
 public class KeyValue<K, V> : IComparable<KeyValue<K, V>>
            where K : IComparable<K>
            where V : IComparable<V>
    {
        //Store the key and the value
        K kKey;
        V vValue;

        public int CompareTo([AllowNull] KeyValue<K, V> other)
        {
            return this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
        }

        //Constructor
        public KeyValue(K key, V value)
        {
            kKey = key;
            vValue = value;
        }

        public K Key
        {
            get
            {
                return kKey;
            }
        }

        public V Value
        {
            get
            {
                return vValue;
            }
        } 
    }
```